# What are the relationships between the motion-time graphs?

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, calculus

I was wondering if someone could explain the relationships between the three motion graphs (Position-Time, Velocity-Time, and Acceleration-Time). I believe that the slope of the P-T is Velocity and the slope of the V-T is Acceleration. I just want to know how they all relate to each other, and how you can find different kinematic variables using each graph.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. The slope of any function (position, velocity, acceleration, number of bananas, etc) plotted along the time axis is the rate of change of that function. If your graph is a straight line, it's easy to find the slope, which is just rise/run, e.g.

$$ \text{velocity} = v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{\text{(change in position)}}{\text{(change in time)}}. $$

To find position from velocity on the other hand (or velocity from acceleration), you need the area under the velocity (or acceleration) versus time graph, since

$$ \Delta x = v\Delta t. $$

When your graph is *not* a straight line, the slope is changing (and areas will be harder to calculate), but the same principle holds in terms of limits, with $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$, $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$. This is where calculus comes in, with slope given by the derivative and area by the integral.